# How to find the subset of all C++ source/header files that were actually used when running a program?

Tags: c++, code-coverage

I have a large project with 1000s of source files and 100s of tests often running for 10s of seconds. So running the whole test suite takes quite a bit of time. Of course each test only utilizes some part of the program in terms of code coverage. So when I change some source files it would be nice to be able to identify which tests need to be re-run.

I think I could do this with compiling the program with code coverage enabled, and then summing up the result to source/header files only per test run. This solution slows down the execution unnecessarily, is there a better way?

Comment: The proper solution is to split the project into multiple smaller projects.

Comment: That's not really an option for several reasons (e.g. organizational), but maybe the most important one is that there are like 100s of sub-components and the tests cover various interesting combinations (out of the 2^N). So there's really no meaningful splitting of the project that would allow running the individual tests on separate binaries.

Comment: If there is no meaningful way of splitting (which I really, reeaaaalllllyyy doubt it) then it means everything is related to everything (spaghetti?) and thus you should always run all tests.

Comment: Code coverage is not sufficient because some external function might not be called even though it should due to a faulty test. I think a test should be run if any linked components change. If you run tests against one monolithic library then you should just run them all. If you run them against e.g. single object files, just re-run only if the corresponding file changed - make can be used here nicely. If this is not good enough, blame your design choices - breaking up large projects is good advice, not just for testing.

Comment: There's no need to re-run a test unless there's a chance that the result would be different. So if a function was not called last time and there was no change that would cause the function to be called now, then the test result would be the same. It doesn't matter if the result is PASS or FAIL, the overall test suite result can still take this into account without running the test.

Comment: If your tests or code have UB then any change in the code or a compiler update can make the test fail all of a sudden. The test might also just randomly fail every 100th run. Any change in the code can also have large impacts on the speed. If you also measure performance of test runs to detect changes in speed then all test have to be run pretty much every time.

Comment: But if you do want to run just the most relevant tests then I agree with frakish. Split your files into smaller translation units and use (partial) LTO to keep optimization the same. Then you can run the test for every TU that was recompiled.